# How to tell user that there is an upgrade of my app?

Tags: android, file, http, save

Now I save in the DB of my server the last version number of my app. When the user perform ad online operation, I control that number and if the version installed on the user device is lower, I show a message 'There is a newer version. Please upgrade'.
To route the user to my server I use a free reroute service, as dyndns...

But what happens if dyndns decides to stop that free service? The app can no more reach my server and the message of the ugrade cannot be showed. So, I think it's better to store ALSO a version.txt file in a web page. And if the dyndns address id no more reachable, I read the **version.txt** stored online.

But, **where to save this file on the web**? There are free service that permit to save a file accessible to everyone? I tried Google Web service, but after a while the file was unreachable.
Are there other similar HTTP sites that permit you to save files for free (with infinite number of readings)?

Thank you all,
Geltry

Comment: I suspect you don't have your app in the market? You could use [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/), it has a nice API, too.

Comment: 1) My app is in the market.  2)Can you be more specific about Gist?

Comment: If it's in the market, the market will take care of updating and notifying the user when a new version is available. For 2, read http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/

Comment: for 1: my app will interface with a DB. If I change DB I need that user upgrade. He cannot have the possibility to choose not to upgrade.

Comment: for 2: I tried Gists... Good idea, but I cannot access directly to my gist... I must link to a page that returns me a json with the link to the last version of my .txt... Too much overhead.

Comment: 1: I guess it's a remote database? Otherwise, this is not a problem. If it is a remote-database, I would put the "please update"-message, when your app fails to load data from it. 2: You should make the HTTP-request from your app and get it's JSON-response, parse it and then you have your file. This can be done in one step.

Comment: 1: a database could not respond for many different problems that an update cannot resolve! 2: With github I download 2000bytes for a pair of bytes of information. However, ok: I start developing in this direction :-)

Comment: 1: It's normally always a bad idea to change something that a current instance relies on. You should keep API's consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using BugSense Crash Report service there is an option there to display a message to the user in the notification drop-down window if there is a new upgrade for the application that has fixed a certain bug.

You can check it out:

http://www.bugsense.com/

Comment: Ok, but this bind me with BugSense... And I need a more free way. BugSense is a third party library (really good library...) and if BugSense decide to turn off my free account, it's the same as having an account on dyndns...